# In the code im following, why is the end part of the program shown every loop?

Tags: javascript

Hi there Im trying to learn javascript by following this book that was aimed at kids and beginners ... in the book one of the exercises is to create a simple hangman game. Im trying to do that now but its not quite working for me like in the book, I have followed the code in the book down to every letter but for me the loops arent working.

The code is meant to obviously keep running until every letter has been guessed then reveal the answer. But for me when I run the code and guess a letter it will run normally and either reveal a letter or not whether or not i got it wrong, but then it will also reveal what the answer is even if i have only guessed one letter , and then keep looping asking for more letters but every loop also revealing the answer. why wont the answer not reveal until the end ? Any help will be appreciated

```
// List of words that will be randomized for player to guess
var words = [
    "computer",
    "library",
    "football",
    "coffee",
    "minecraft",
    "movie",
    "Jessica"
];

var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

var answerArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    answerArray[i] = " _ ";
}

var remaingLetters = word.length;

while (remaingLetters > 0) {
    // Bulk of Game code

//show the player the current progress
alert(answerArray.join(""));

//recieve guess from player and check it is a single letter
var guess = prompt("Guess a letter, or click Cancel to stop playing");
if(guess === null) {
    break;
} else if (guess.length !== 1){
    alert("please enter a single letter.");
} else {
    //update the game
    for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
        if(word[j] === guess) {
            answerArray[j] = guess;
            remaingLetters--;
        }
    }
}

alert(answerArray.join(" "));
alert("Good job! The Answer was " + word);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you indent the code, it becomes clear.

```
while (remaingLetters > 0) {
    // Bulk of Game code

    //show the player the current progress
    alert(answerArray.join(""));

    //recieve guess from player and check it is a single letter
    var guess = prompt("Guess a letter, or click Cancel to stop playing");
    if(guess === null) {
        break;
    } else if (guess.length !== 1){
        alert("please enter a single letter.");
    } else {
        //update the game
        for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
            if(word[j] === guess) {
                answerArray[j] = guess;
                remaingLetters--;
            }
        }
    }

    alert(answerArray.join(" "));
    alert("Good job! The Answer was " + word);


}//this is the end of the while
```

Your code is inside the loop, so it will be executed every time. It should be outside the loop

Comment: Although many may disagree, this is a good, correct and complete answer as it would be helpful advice to future visitors who are likely to be in the same boat.

Comment: thank you, yes need to get used to indenting better :p

Comment: very good remark about the indentation. I had to indeed read it twice before answering. It deserves an additional vote :)

Answer (score 1):

You display the word to find after the conditional statements.

So this code :

```
alert("Good job! The Answer was " + word);
```

is executed at each loop.

The word was guessed as you exit the loop :

```
while (remaingLetters > 0)
```

So it means that you should display the end message with the guessed word only when you go out of the `while`.

So these statements :

```
alert(answerArray.join(" "));
alert("Good job! The Answer was " + word);
```

should be placed after the while.